# Solution for downloading hundreds of files asynchronously

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, httprequest

I have an app in which the user may need to download up to 760 files, totaling around 350MB. It is *not* possible to zip these files, they must be downloaded as loose files!

I'm currently using [Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) to download individual files, and `AsyncTask` to run the entire process.

Here's an example of a `DownloadThread` object which handles downloading hundreds of files in the background:

```
public class DownloadThread extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

ArrayList<String> list;
AsyncHttpClient client;
String[] allowedContentTypes = new String[] { "audio/mpeg" };
BufferedOutputStream bos;
FileOutputStream fos;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    DownloadTask task;
    for (String file : list) {
        //the "list" variable has already been populated with hundreds of strings
        task = new DownloadTask(file);
        task.execute("");
        while (!task.isdone)
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    return null;
}


class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    String character, filename;
    boolean isdone = false;

    public DownloadTask(String file) {
        //file = something like "Whale/sadwhale.mp3"
        character = file.split("/")[0];
        filename = file.split("/")[1];
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (!result.equals("Error")) {
                        //Do something on success
        }
        isdone = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... str) {
        client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get("http://some-site.com/sounds/" + character + "/"
                + filename, new BinaryHttpResponseHandler(
                allowedContentTypes) {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(byte[] fileData) {
                try {
                    // Make file/folder and create stream
                    File folder = new File(Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + CharSelect.directory + character);
                    folder.mkdirs();
                    File dest = new File(folder, filename);
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(dest);
                    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                    // Transfer data to file
                    bos.write(fileData);
                    bos.flush();
                    bos.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        return "Success";
    }

}
```

}

`DownloadThread` runs in the background, and also calls hundreds of it's own `AsyncTasks`. It waits until the task is done downloading, then continues the `for` loop for each download.

This works, kinda. Some downloads appear to not finish properly or not start at all. Out of a list of 760 downloads, an average of 100 downloads complete properly, and I have to restart the process to download another additional 100 downloads until that one fails as well. I have a feeling this is due to timing issues, as the `Thread.sleep(10)` line seems a little "hackish".

Surely, calling hundreds of `AsyncTasks` from another `AsyncTask` is not the most efficient way to do this. How can I alter this code or implement a 3rd party solution to fit this task?

Comment: Do they really need to be downloaded asynchronously? I feel like putting them in a queue and downloading one at a time would be fine.

Comment: It doesn't _have_ to, but by doing this asynchronously I can (eventually) manage 2 or 3 downloads at a time, increasing the overall speed. Of course, I need a reliable method first.

Answer (score 3):

Try out [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) API. This should be what you need.

Comment: I didn't realize this was built in O_O Will definitely take a look!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the thing you need to keep in mind:

Computers have limited resources; network bandwidth, CPU, memory, disk, etc

The time it takes to download 1 file at a time vs. 760 files simultaneous can never logically take any longer than simultaneous download.

However, by spawning a whole lot of background tasks/threads you are incurring a lot of thread thrashing/overhead as each one needs to be context switched in and out. CPU bandwidth will be consumed in the switching instead of actually moving data in and off of the network interface. In addition, each thread will consume it's own memory and potentially need creating if not part of a pool.

Basically the reason your app isn't working reliably/at all is almost certainly because it's running out of CPU/DISK-IO/memory resources well before it finishes the downloads or fully utilizes the network.

Solution: find a library to do this or make use of the Executor suite of classes and use a limited pool of threads (then only download a few at a time).

Here is some good evidence in the wild that what you're trying to do is not advised:

- Google play updates are all serialized
- Amazon MP3 file downloader is totally serialized
- default scp client in Linux is serialized file transfer
- Windows update downloads serially

Getting the picture? Spewing all those threads is a recipe for problems in return for perceived speed improvement.